# show/hide ag-grid with angular

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid

I want to hide the grid if I don't have data. I am using angular so I am doing it with ng-show="vm.showGrid" , after my grid is displayed it is not looking good until I am scrolling the grid or just resizing my page. 
What can fix it ?

Comment: Programatcially scroll down by a single pixel

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what do you mean by not looking good, so I am assuming the columns size in the grid doesn't meet your expectation. If that's the case, you can call these mentions **AFTER** you show the grid.

1) `gridAPI.sizeColumnsToFit()`, to get columns to adjust in size to fit the grid horizontally.

2) `columnAPI.autoSizeColumns(colKeys)`, you can pass all the columns as colKeys to auto size all the columns